# ajax async:false, blocks the animated gif loading image

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working in .Net web application.

I done few ajax calls synchronously(async:false), since I need to get the value of ajax result in local varaiable.

But If I make a loading visible when it enters into the ajax, it is working fine in firefox, Chrome and IE does not support.

Please help me, any work around for this???

```
function findtempvalues(tempparam) {
                var tempnamevalues = new Array();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Services/Locale.asmx/templatename",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ tempwidpath: tempparam }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        tempnamevalues = result.d;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    },
                    timeout: 3000
                });
                return tempnamevalues;
            }
```

Comment: You should refactor your code to work asynchronously. This blocking won't then occur.

Comment: solution 1: pre-load your gif. solution 2: do the loading visible before you make the ajax call. make a wrapper function for the ajax call which first enables your gif, then will do the ajax call passing the appropriate variables. see if adding a small delay before the ajax call works.

Comment: I tried adding a new div using .prepend also before the ajax starts. But it doesnt working still

Comment: I want to make the code asynchronous and also i need to get the response in a variable. How can I achieve this??

Comment: Like Mike suggest, you should make an asynchronous call if you don't want to block your navigator. Maybe if you post your code we can help you.

Comment: gaepi: I posted my code here, can you have a look on it?

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous call and `.done(function(data){ //handle data... })` to retrieve data's.

Answer (score 0):

To make an asynchronous call and display a loading message

```
function findtempvalues(tempparam)
{
    $('#loadingMessage').css('visibility', 'visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/Locale.asmx/templatename",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ tempwidpath: tempparam }),
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            callback(result)
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#loadingMessage').css("visibility", "hidden");
        },
        timeout: 3000
    });
}

function callback(result)
{
    var tempnamevalues = new Array();
    tempnamevalues = result.d

    // continue ...
}
```

Get your result in a callback function, don't make a "return"

And in your HTML you have something like that :

```
<span id="loadingMessage" style="visibility: hidden;">Loading ...</span>
```